# Which following sentences are correct?

Tags: grammar

I want to ask my friend where he gonna stay this week. please tell me which following sentences are correct.

> Will you in Taipei this week?
>   Will you be in Taipei this week?
>   Will you stay in Taipei this week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is incorrect (it doesn't have a verb), while either of the others could be depending on what you want to say.

> Will you be in Taipei this week?

This sentence is the more neutral, only asking if they will be in Taipei at some point during the week, either for a long period of time or a short one. This will work for just about any situation.

> Will you stay in Taipei this week?

The verb "stay" in this sentence implies being in Taipei for a longer time, the entire week. You can switch out the phrase "this week" for another specific time such as "tomorrow" or "Tuesday" to ask about those time frames instead. This is the more specific question, if you're wondering about long term plans.

Comment: Sorry, it's irrelative, do I need to put a `for` before `this week` in the sentence?

Comment: @Ives not if you're talking about a specific time. You would if you're talking about a period of time: `will you stay in Taipei for a week?` or `will you be in Taipei for three hours?`

Comment: OK, I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want to know if where he is staying, you would ask

> Will you **stay** in Taipei this week?

Your first example is ungrammatical.

Your second example may be true, that he is "***in***" Taipei, but he may not "***stay***" in Taipei.